# How can I pass an argument to callback while calling it from sort method

Tags: javascript, callback

How can I pass an argument to callback method while calling it from [arrayobj.sort(sortFunction)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b4fbfhk(v=vs.94).aspx)  method.I want to pass "sortOrder" to "Compare" as well to sort it accending or desecding.

```
var sortOrder = "asc";
var a = new Array(4, 11, 2, 10, 3, 1);
b = a.sort(Compare);   // how to pass "sortOrder" here

// Sorts array elements in ascending order numerically.
function Compare(first, second, sortOrder) // here sortOrder require 
{
    if(sortOrder == "asc"){
        if (first == second)
            return 0;
        if (first < second)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1; 
        }
    else{
        if (first == second)
            return 0;
        if (first < second)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1; 
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: For inline anonymous functions always prefer arrows  `a.sort((p,c) => compare(p,c))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution returns a function for the selected sort order. If no order is specified, then the function for `asc` is used.

```js
function getComparer(sortOrder) {
    return sortOrder === 'desc' ?
        function (a, b) { return b - a; } :
        function (a, b) { return a - b; };
}

var a = new Array(4, 11, 2, 10, 3, 1);

a.sort(getComparer());
document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
a.sort(getComparer('desc'));
document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Nice. But I'd suggest changing the name of your "compare" function to something like "generateCompare" or something like that :) , it confused me for a second.

Comment: @RubenSerrate, better now?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

Replace

```
b = a.sort(Compare);
```

with

```
b = a.sort(function(a,b){
  return Compare(a, b, sortOrder);
});
```

DEMO

```js
var sortOrder = "asc";
var a = new Array(4, 11, 2, 10, 3, 1);
b = a.sort(function(a,b){
  return Compare(a, b, sortOrder);
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(b,0,4);

function Compare(first, second, sortOrder) // here sortOrder require
{
    if(sortOrder == "asc"){
        if (first == second)
            return 0;
        if (first < second)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1; 
        }
    else{
        if (first == second)
            return 0;
        if (first < second)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1; 
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only use for your code is the one you've posted here, you can just remove `sortOrder` from the list of parameters, so that the variable you define at the top is still visible inside the function.

If not, either of the two previous answers are the way to go.